# Converting angular velocity to rad/sec in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to convert an RPM to radians/sec using Matlab with the following commands:

```
w=9.55;
a = convangvel([w],'rpm','rad/s')
```

This returns this error:

```
Undefined function 'convangvel' for input arguments of type 'double'.
```

What am I doing wrong here? This is the syntax provided by the MATLAB site so I'm unsure of what else to do.

Comment: This function is in the Aerospace toolbox - do you have that installed?

Comment: No, I don't; schoolboy error! Thanks for the help.